# PC to virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

Currently I'm moving from old PC to new one. I have windows 7 installed. I'm planning throw away old PC, but before that I would like to have possibility to run old PC operating system just in case I forgot how to configure application or just forgot file. It is not enough to have file system, I need to have possibility to run whole OS. It would be nice for example to have Vmware image of my old PC. Is it possible somehow make virtual PC from hardware PC?

Comment: Remove the hard disc form old pc and install it in the new PC and run the OS whenever you want.

Comment: Don't throw away the old machine -- you can never have too many computers!

Answer (score 0):

Symantec System Recovery 2011 or greater.

[image: Symantec System Recovery 2011]

Convert VM and backup image:

[VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Client](http://www.vmware.com/ru/products/converter/)

[image: VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Client version 5]

[image: VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Client convert dialog]